Как разбить многомерный массив на множество одномерных
У меня массив byte[][][] array = new byte[][][]{};.
Из библиотек есть apache lang3 и google.
Мне нужно получить каждый из массивов
  public byte[] getFirst() {
    byte[] a1 = один из преобразованных массивов;
    
    return a1;
  }

21 java.

Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте в него пример, а так же желаемый результат.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

А что именно вы хотите получить в результате разбиения исходного многомерного массива, некую коллекцию одномерных массивов?  И что должен делать неправильный метод с недопустимым названием void?

Несмотря на правку, вопрос понятнее не стал.  С чем именно проблема, вы не знаете как проитерироваться по многомерному массиву несколько раз, чтобы получить в результате одномерный массив?

Если нужно разбить трёхмерный массив на множество одномерных, то достаточно использовать циклы, и не надо никаких библиотек.Пример:
//Возьмём такой массив
byte[][][] array = new byte[][][] {
        {
            {3, 4, 5}, {45, 30, -43}     
        }, 
        {
            {4}, {30, -44, -23, 90}, {0, 3}         
        }
};

//Разбиваем его на одномерные и складываем в HashSet
Set<byte[]> setOfArrays = new HashSet<>();
for(byte[][] i : array) {
    for(byte[] j : i) {
        setOfArrays.add(j);
    }
}

//Выводим на экран, чтобы посмотреть, что получилось
for(byte[] current : setOfArrays) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(current));
}

Вывод:
[45, 30, -43]
[3, 4, 5]
[0, 3]
[30, -44, -23, 90]
[4]

Если вам важен порядок, то следует использовать не множество, а список, стек или очередь. Код будет аналогичный, нужно будет только заменить HashSet на нужную вам коллекцию. Если, например, вы выберете список (любую реализацию List), то получить первый массив можно будет так:
byte[] first = listOfArrays.getFirst(); 


Если вам важен порядок, достаточно всего лишь использовать LinkedHashSet вместо HashSet.  Если вдруг нужно получить самый первый массив, его можно сразу же вернуть из глубины вложенных циклов или получить из стрима Arrays.stream(array3d).flatMap(Arrays::stream).findFirst().orElse(null); и т.д.  Но к сожалению, автор вопроса не раскрыл суть своей проблемы.
